# find: How to use found paths in the -exec directive?

Tags: bash, shell, find, exec

I have a dozen files named

```
~/DOMAIN1.de/bin/dbdeploy.php
~/DOMAIN2.de/bin/dbdeploy.php
~/DOMAIN3.de/bin/dbdeploy.php
```

I want to run them all with the same arguments.
My bash script reads:

```
cd ~
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*\.de" -exec php56 bin/dbdeploy.php "$1" "$2" \;
```

However, the path given to exec seems not to be relative to the found subdirectory but rather to my PWD:

```
$ bash -x ./.dbpush "some argument"
+ cd ~
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*\.de' -exec php56 bin/dbdeploy.php 'some argument' ';'
Could not open input file: bin/dbdeploy.php
Could not open input file: bin/dbdeploy.php
Could not open input file: bin/dbdeploy.php
```

**How can I use the found path in the -exec directive?**

Comment: Not answering your question, but achieving the same goal using your shell instead of the external utility `find`: `for d in ~/*.de/bin/dbdeploy.php; do php56 "$d" "$1" "$2"; done`.

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf! I used the idea of searching the whole filename and got rid of those "file does not exist" errors: 
    find . -type f -wholename "*\.de/bin/dbdeploy.php" -exec  php56 {} "$1" "$2" \;

Comment: In your case, I still believe that the shell is superior to `find` (and it's more portable too, as you're using non-standard (GNU) extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually I found the answer myself:

The "find"-results are stored in {}, so the line reads

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*\.de" -exec  php56 {}/bin/dbdeploy.php "$1" "$2" \;
```

Alternativly

```
find . -type f -wholename "*\.de/bin/dbdeploy.php" -exec  php56 {} "$1" "$2" \;
```